# Upgrading Intel's Android Images to a newer API level?

Tags: android-emulator

I'd like to use Intel Accelerated Android Emulator images. I noticed that API 16 has a `Intel x86 Atom System Image` but API 17 does not. Is this by design or they simply haven't gotten around to generating it yet?

Is there a way to upgrade the API 16 image to work with level 17 APIs?

Comment: How can this question be off-topic when http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857325/google-maps-sdk-with-new-intel-atom-x86-emulator was not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API 17 has support for the x86 system image.[image: x86 System Image for API 17]

Comment: Sure took them long enough... :)

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, the same situation was with API 16. And one day Intel released their image.
So, as you said:

> they simply haven't gotten around to generating it yet

I'm not competent enough to answer on your second question, but I dont think that it's possibe or it's just not worth it (if it was possible, I think we would already have Intel System Images for more than 3 APIs).